# Using a python subprocess to run another python script that contains os.ctermid()

Tags: python, subprocess

I have written a small python script that runs another python script and does some basic processing on its output. It then uses this output as part of a sublime-text plugin.

It executes the second python script (whose source I have no control over) by uisng subprocess.Popen

It works except for one issue. The second python script has a function containing the following code

```
try:
  with open(os.ctermid(), "rb") as f:
    height, width = struct.unpack("hh", ioctl(f.fileno(), TIOCGWINSZ, "1234"))
  except (IOError, OSError, struct.error):
    # return default size if actual size can't be determined
    __warn_terminal_width_once()
    return __default_terminal_width
return width
```

This exception always triggers on the command `open(os.ctermid(), "rb")`.
While I can work with the default output size and filter out the warning, it would be much nicer to be able to somehow set things up so that ctermid() succeeds. Is this possible?

Edit: If I comment out the try block the exception that is printed is

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_tools/common.py", line 445, in terminal_width_linux
    with open(os.ctermid(), "rb") as f:
IOError: [Errno 6] No such device or address: '/dev/tty'
```

Also if it helps the full source of my code is [here](https://github.com/ZacharyTaylor/Catkin-Builder/blob/master/CatkinBuild.py#L61) with the subprocess call happening at line 61

Comment: `os.ctermid()` is only available on Unix operating systems. What OS are you on? Also please update your question to include the exception it gives.

Comment: This is running on Ubuntu 16.04. The try block in the second script was catching the exception, I edited it out and updated the question with its output.

Comment: It's trying to get the window size, but that only works if it has a controlling terminal. You are running it through a pipe (Popen) so the subprocess' stdin is not a terminal. So it will always fail.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for but I guess I'll just have to work around the issue. Thanks for the help.